# ¿Por qué no funciona mi botón de hipotenusa?

Tags: javascript, html

Éste es el código de mi formulario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="funciones4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo4.css">
        <title>Botones</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="transparent">
<div class="index2.1">
    <marquee>ESCOGE UNO PLOX</marquee>
    <form name="index2.3" action="index2.3.html" method="POST" id="index2.3">
    <center>
        <fieldset>
            <button href="index2.3.html" id="hipot" onclick= "hipotenusa()">H I P O T E N U S A</button><br><br>
            <button href="index2.2.html" id="seno" onclick= "sen()">SEN α </button>in
        </fieldset>
    </center>

    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Al presionar el botón hipotenusa manda a esta pantalla:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="funciones4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo4.css">
    <title>Practica 2.4</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="transparent">
    <div class="index2.3">
        <marquee>HOLA AMIGOS</marquee>
        <!--<form name="funciones" action="index" method="POST" id="funciones">-->
            <center>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>CATETO ADYACENTE</label>
                    <input placeholder="Escribe algo porfa" type="numb" id="c_ady"><br><br>
                    <label>CATETO OPUESTO</label>
                    <input placeholder="Escribe algo porfa" type="numb" id="c_op"><br><br>
                    <button style="width:50%" id="hipot" onclick="hipotenusa()">M O S T R A R</button>
                </fieldset>
            </center>

        <!--/form-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ésta es la función de hipotenusa:

```
function hipotenusa() {

  var c_ady; var c_op;

  hipot= Math.sqrt((c_ady*c_ady) + (c_op*c_op));

}
```

Comment: tus variables no estan definidas.

Comment: Entonces cuando las pongo en la funcion no es definirlas? :c

Comment: O como las defino?

Comment: Luego de calcular la hipotenusa, donde quieres mostrar el resultado??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifica tu funcion javascript por lo siguiente si lo que quieres es tomar los valores de los campos en el formulario:

```
   function hipotenusa() {
        var c_ady = document.getElementById('c_ady').value;
        var c_op = document.getElementById('c_op').value;

        hipot = Math.sqrt((c_ady * c_ady) + (c_op * c_op));
        alert('El valor de la hipotenusa es: ' + hipot);
    }
```

Comment: GRACIASSSS ME SIRVIO MUCHO

Comment: Se vale votar :) por esta solucion.